# GMAIL API doesn't accept most queries (GAE Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I'm trying to fetch all sent messages for the last 3 months, using a Google App Engine app on Python. For some reason though it doesn't accept most of the queries that I enter. It returns results for a simple string, but if I enter something like "after:2015/01/20", or "newer_than:3m"  it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

I have no clue where this could be coming from. My current code for the request is:

```
import webapp2, httplib2
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
from apiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client import client
from google.appengine.api import memcache

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
service = discovery.build("gmail", "v1", http=http)
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
                        client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
                        scope=settings.SCOPE)

class retrieveMessages(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    try:
        user = 'someone@gmail.com'
        after = (datetime.datetime.now()+relativedelta(months=-3)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        query = 'after:'+after
        http = decorator.http()
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user, labelIds='SENT', q=query, maxResults=1000).execute(http=http)
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])

        while 'nextPageToken' in response:
          page_token = response['nextPageToken']
          response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user, labelIds='SENT', q=query, pageToken=page_token).executehttp=http(http=http)
          messages.extend(response['messages'])

        return messages
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
        if error.resp.status == 401:
          # Credentials have been revoked.
          # TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
          raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: I figured. The question is what the bug is...

Comment: the second messages().list() call is just "service.messages().list()" not "service.users().messages().list().

Comment: I used the Google example from here which in that case contains the same error: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#send_authorized_requests_and_check_for_revoked_credentials

Comment: Heh odd, guess that's a bug in the Google docs also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this snippet inside the while loop:

```
response = service.messages()...
```

be

```
response = service.users().messages()...
```

Comment: Turns out I was also missing "http=http" on the second execute(). I've updated the code above. Works perfectly fine now, thanks!